# ExtJS PropertyGrid - Dynamically setting source

Tags: javascript, extjs, propertygrid

I am working on a simple PropertyGrid. If I set the source property with some json object at design time, it is displaying properly. But when I tried setting the source data dynamically, it is not displaying data.

This is my code:

```
ConceptPropertiesPanel = function() {

    this.source = {   ***// if i set source this way, it will work***

    "(name)": "My Object",
    "Created": new Date(Date.parse('10/15/2006')),  
    "Available": false,  
    "Version": .01,     
    "Description": "A test object"
};

ConceptPropertiesPanel.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
    id: 'concetp-properties',
    region: 'east',
    title: 'Concept Properties',
    autoScroll: true,
    margins: '0 5 0 0',
    split: true,
    width: 250,
    minSize: 250,
    maxSize: 400,
    collapsible: true,
    source: {}
})
};


Ext.extend(ConceptPropertiesPanel, Ext.grid.PropertyGrid, {

setSourceData: function(data) { **//I want to set source when the below method is called, but not working**
    this.setSource({
        "(name)": "My Object",
        "Created": new Date(Date.parse('10/15/2006')),  
        "Available": false,  
        "Version": .01,     
        "Description": "A test object"
    });
}

});
```

This is how I am calling the 'setSourceData' function.

```
var conceptPropertiesPanel = new ConceptPropertiesPanel();
conceptPropertiesPanel.setSourceData(data);
```

Can anyone let me know where the problem is in the code?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/akat/UgLN4/3/) is your code with demo. It works as expected. You may want to check if there are any JS errors when you invoke `conceptPropertiesPanel.setSourceData(data);` otherwise it *should* work!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but that would be setting Source after the object is already initialized, which would require you to find the object's update to `update()`, or `doLayout()` to update the presentation of the data.

Another option is in your original function call to take a config. Something like:

```
ConceptPropertiesPanel = function(config) {

this.source = config || {   ***// if i set source this way, it will work***

    "(name)": "My Object",
    "Created": new Date(Date.parse('10/15/2006')),  
    "Available": false,  
    "Version": .01,     
    "Description": "A test object"
};
```

Comment: I tried using the doLayout() but it is not working.

Also, with the above code. but same behaviour.

Is there any alternative way of achieving the required functionality.